# How to define and use a struct without full struct definition in header?

Tags: c, struct, c89, design-guidelines

For controling struct members and force programmers to use getter/setter functions, I want to write code like below pattern:

```
/* Header file: point.h */
...
/* define a struct without full struct definition. */
struct point;

/* getter/setter functions. */
int point_get_x(const struct point* pt);
void point_set_x(struct point* pt, int x);
...

//--------------------------------------------

/* Source file: point.c */
struct point
{
  int x, y;
};

int point_get_x(const struct point* pt) {return pt->x; }

void point_set_x(struct point* pt, int x) {pt->x = x;}

//--------------------------------------------

/* Any source file: eg. main.c */

#include "point.h"
int main()
{
  struct point pt;

  // Good: cannot access struct members directly.
  // He/She should use getter/setter functions.
  //pt.x = 0;

  point_set_x(&pt, 0);
}
```

But this code does not compile with MSVC++ 2010.

Which changes should I do for compiling?

Note: I use ANSI-C (C89) standard, Not C99 or C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `make_point` function in point.c to create the point; main.c doesn't know how big the structure is.

Also

```
typedef struct point point;
```

will support using `point` rather than `struct point` in declarations.

Answer (score 3):

```
  point pt;
```

The name of the type is `struct point`. You have to use the whole thing every time, or you need to `typedef` it.<sup>*</sup>

I.e. you should write

```
  struct point pt;
```

there in `main`.

---

You are probably thinking of `FILE*` and things like it from the standard library and want to duplicate that behavior. To do that use

```
struct s_point
typedef struct s_point point;
```

in the header. (There are shorter ways to write that, but I want to avoid confusion.) This declares a type named `struct s_point` and assigns it an alias `point`.

---

(*) Notice that this differs from c++, where `struct point` declares a type called `point` which is a `struct`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot it :) . But another error appers: `error C2079: 'pt' uses undefined struct 'point'`

Comment: See Doug's answer for that: `main` doesn't know how big a `point` is, so you want to make a `point*` there an get the allocation from the library code.